# print out the content of a modified file

Tags: php

I am having a problem with outputting a modified file in php, here is my code:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("1.txt");
$items = explode("\n",$content);
$line = ""; 
foreach ($items as $item){
$values = explode(",",$item);
foreach ($values as &$value){
    $key = array_search($value,$values);
    if ($key!=4){
        $line .= $value.",";
    }
    elseif ($value=="0"){
        $value="?";
        $line .= $value."\n";
    }
    else $line .= $value."\n";
}
}
$file = fopen("1.txt","w");
fwrite($file,$line);
fclose($file); 
?>
```

The original content in 1.txt is

```
1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,0
```

The desired output is to be

```
1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,?
```

However, I got this when I run the script:

```
1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,?
,
```

What is the problem of my script? Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for Robik, anyway i have just tested your original script and it works fine for me. Maybe you want to read http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=8021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not connecting lines with `\n` correctly. Here's my bit modified function:

```
$content = '1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,0';

$lines = explode("\n", $content);

$modLines = array();

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $values = explode(',', $line);

    foreach($values as &$value)
    {
        # Do here what ever you want to
         if($value == '0')
        $value = '?';
    }

    $modLines[] = implode(',', $values);

}

$content = implode("\n", $modLines);

echo $content;
```

Returns

```
1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,?
```