# Php Array when exceed certain numbers

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have a php associative array which contains more approximately 900 key-value and i am using it as a string file. The problem is now when I add another key-value , I am unable to retrieve the value by key. How ever if i delete some other key-value it works fine. I wonder if there is any size limit for array. Please help me, i don't want to split my array into different files.
Thank you in advance. This is what y string file looks like

```
function lang($phrase){
static $lang = array(   
't_sust_tour'=>'tour',
'process_report'=>'p report '
);
return $lang[$phrase];
}
```

Comment: heard of databases? however 900 is no where near the limit

Comment: Give us an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ya but i don't want to use database. And if it is not near the limit than why i am unable to retrieve the value? I just get a blank value whenever i call array by key

Comment: show us some code and we may be able to answer this

Comment: Please post some more code. You have 900 elements in this function by adding all the elements to the array staticly? Anyway, before you return check that the index is isset: if (isset($lang[$phrase])) { return $lang[$phrase] } else { echo "Not isset: " . $phrase; exit; } And please test it with some index that does not work. Maybe something wrong with your indexes.

Comment: However when i call the key in the same function file it works. But when i use the same function in a different file some key doesn't work. it give blank value.

Answer (score -1):

There is no max or limit, but it is how much memory your script will consume which can be adjusted in the 'memory_limit' in your php.ini configuration.

here is answer from a previous SO post [Array size limit in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925885/array-size-limit-in-php)

Comment: As far as I read on SO and some-other forums the only limit is the memory_limit setting in php.ini that can be changed. why the down vote by the way?

Comment: please provide an explanation and a reason for down voting my answer.

Comment: Well, i did not down voted. I hav'nt ear that reputation to do so